# simple_form devise ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1, 0))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

I have upgraded rails to 5.0.0.1 and ruby 2.3.0 now I'm getting following error in my devise view using simple_form

> ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):

at this line of code

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

I have googled this for hours and cannot find any solution,

my devise version is 4.2.0 and simple_form 3.3.1

Comment: Please share the stacktrace.

Comment: @mudasobwa is this what you're asking for https://gist.github.com/riksof-zzlalani/74252563cfd787c419dac9400c521f83

Comment: Sounds like `registration_path` does not require an argument anymore. Try to remove it and see if it works.

Comment: @mudasobwa I tried that and it doesn't work either

Comment: Did you find any answer to it? I too invested a lot but unable to understand with similar versions.